# GOOGLE APPS SCRIPT:remove Duplicate row ( compare col C and D with rest rows)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

i have a spreadsheet with 7 columns, i want delete duplicate rows. But i need compare col C and D values with the others rows. if there are another row with the same value (col C and D) just deletes it, i tried use the "unique function", but this compare all cols values.

|  | colA | colB | colC | colD | colE | colF | colG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| row1 | short | walter | **white | size2** | 2019 | enero | 0002 |
| row2 | pants | Carlos | green | size3 | 2019 | julio | 0003 |
| row3 | boxer | Felipe | **white | size2** | 2020 | marzo | 0005 |
| row4 | tshirt | walter | **yellow | size1 | ** 2019 | junio | 0002 |
| row5 | sock | Martin | **yellow | size1 | ** 2021 | mayo | 0005 |

In the example before (just comparing Col C and col D) i need delete row 3 (the same value in row1) and row 5 (the same valueS row 4)

I need google script code to do that.

any can help me?

Comment: Anyone know of a way to do this without App Scripts? I got stuck trying to build a filter on the array of everything matching.

Comment: @pgSystemTester Added a answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
function deleteDupes() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const rg = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1,sh.getLastColumn());
  const vs = rg.getDisplayValues();
  let d = 0;
  let uA = [];
  let oA = [];
  vs.forEach((r,i) =>  {
    let t = String(r[2]+r[4]);
    if(!~uA.indexOf(t) {
      uA.push(t);
      oA.push(r);
    }
  });
  rg.clearContent();
  sh.getRange(2,1,oA.length,oA[0],length).setValues(oA);
}
```

Comment: i have Error ReferenceError: length is not defined"error"  (last line....)

Answer (score 1):

As a formula,

```
=FILTER(A1:G5,MATCH(C1:C5&D1:D5,C1:C5&D1:D5,0)=ROW(C1:C5))
```

- Create a joint array of col C and col D using `&`
- `MATCH` to match the array among itself to get a matching row number
- Compare the `MATCH` result with actual `ROW` number. This generates a TRUE/FALSE array of duplicates
- `FILTER` the entire table using the duplicates array above.

[Example file here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16liUgWxbntkumY1asLakQURk3vWKbX9vP_R9LkzsJow/)

Comment: Dang. That is indeed most clever with leveraging the `Row` with the `Match`. Upvoting this answer and I'll go find another answer of yours to give an up click to (which probably won't be hard).  I am going to edit your answer to include an example just because it's awesome. If for some reason you don't approve, just edit it back...